# Why makefiles compiles with -c flag

Tags: c, linux, makefile

[image: screen of my makefile]

as you can see in no rules I tell the makefile to compile with the `-c` flag but he does, can somebody explain me why?

Comment: please don't post screenshots of code. Simply copy and paste your code into the question as text, and mark it as code (there's a button in the question editor".

Comment: Have you figured out what the `-c` flag does? That very likely answers your question, and feels like the intuitive research to do yourself. All we can do is basically copy and paste the text from your compiler's documentation.

Comment: The way I've always thought about is that CFLAGS isn't *all* the C flags.  There are some special cases that `make` is hardwired to just always throw in, and `-c` is one of those — because Makefiles virtually always separate compiling and linking, so you always want `-c` when you're building all your `.o`'s.

Comment: Thank you @SteveSummit, i understand it now

Answer (score 4):

You do not have a rule to make a `.o` file from a `.c` file in your Makefile, so `make` uses its default rule:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $@ $*.c
```

Answer (score 1):

See the makefile manual on [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules):

> Compiling C programs
>
> n.o is made automatically from n.c with a recipe of the form ‘`$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c`’.

If you wish to avoid this, define [an explicit rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Example.html#Rule-Example).